# Media Player Classic often fails to keep always on top

Tags: media-player-classic

I use the latest Media Player Classic Home Cinema version (v1.7.13), and I like its *Always on top* feature (the player remains on top, no matter what other windows I open).

Unfortunately, this (seemingly easy) feature works only 80-90% of the cases. 
Sometimes the window falls behind any other windows.
You can see it in action:
https://streamable.com/xndzo

What could cause this? Windows 10 bugs? MPC-HC bugs? After a few restarts, it is fixed but it is very annoying that such an easy feature fails to work. What setting should I activate to make it permanent?

Comment: This appears to be "normal" Windows [mis]behavior. Even the Windows Task Bar, when hidden and then "popped up", occasionally is hidden behind other applications -- including those that are not set *on top*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik So basically I cannot fix it with any settings in the program...

Comment: Regrettably, it seems so, though I'd be glad if someone else knows a fix for topmost window issues.

Comment: How about Deskpins?  Even then sometimes if there's another window that is always on top it can get hidden. If that's the case, I have once seen a question about keeping a window on top of a window that is set to be on top.